# How can I make a kit that has Unbreakable Items in it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make kits with Unbreakable Items in it for my Kit PvP server.

To make the items Unbreakable, I use this command:

```
 /give (Name) minecraft:(item) 1 0 {Unbreakable:1}
```

For proof that the command worked, I hovered over the item and it clearly said Unbreakable at the bottom of the lore. For example:

[image: Unbreakable]

Problem is, when I do /createkit, it transfers the item but not the Unbreakable effect.

When I hover over the item after I create the kit, it does not say Unbreakable at the bottom of the lore. Again, for example:

[image: Not Unbreakable when I did /kit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `unbreakable` attribute, use the `ench` attribute to add almost infinite unbreaking to the item. (It is still possible to break it, but it would have to deal the damage of killing about 130,000 ender dragons) The command is `/give (Name) minecraft:(item) 1 0 {ench:[{id:34,lvl:10000}]}`.
The item now has unbreaking level 10,000.

Answer (score 1):

By the command it seems like you're using a plugin. If you have essentialsx on your server, which is a pretty common and good to have plugin (in addition to its capable kit system), the following kits.yml is valid and works as expected.

```
kits:
  tools:
    delay: 10
    items:
      - stonesword 1 Unbreakable:true
```